# Failing test for predict k nearest Neighbors function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, machine-learning

[image]

Apparently the function predict itself works well and the whole model gets 75% success. But when I tried to do a test case for the function to check if it will return the correct outcome (1), I get the error `outcomes = np.append(outcomes, y_train[n]) IndexError: index 160 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3`. Any suggestions to what could be the bug?

Comment: Kindly amend your question to align with the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, in order for the community to have a better picture about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to debug based on your screenshot alone. Please provide a minimal working example in the future.

In this particular case, I **assume** that `y_train[n]` tries to access `y_train[160]`, but your `y_train` only has three elements `[1, 1, 0]`. So I assume that `get_neighbors` does not return the type of data that you expect.

It appears that you are using PyCharm. Try to execute the very same code with the built-in debugger (a bug next to the *run* icon), wait for the Exception to appear (it will pause the code at that point), and check the content of your `neighbors` variable in the debugger menu. It should give you more hints.